# Connection is not establishing with redis 7 server using StackExchange.Redis 2.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, redis, .net-7.0, stackexchange.redis

Connection is not establishing with **redis 7** server using **StackExchange.Redis 2.7.17**. But the same code works with **redis 6** server.

Is **StackExchange.Redis 2.7.17** compatible with **redis 7**. Please share your views or any alteranative nuget package that connects redis 7

```
using (StringWriter logs = new StringWriter())
 {   
         var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("redisserver");
         options.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
         ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options, logs);
         var result = connectionMultiplexer.IsConnected // output is always false
 }
```

***please find the below logs***

'"13:47:45.2344: Connecting (sync) on .NET 7.0.16 (StackExchange.Redis: v2.7.17.27058)\n13:47:45.2678: redisserver:6379,syncTimeout=1000,allowAdmin=True,connectTimeout=1000,ssl=False,abortConnect=False\n13:47:45.2779: redisserver:6379/Interactive: Connecting...\n13:47:45.2908: redisserver:6379: BeginConnectAsync\n13:47:45.2946: 1 unique nodes specified (with tiebreaker)\n13:47:45.2956: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync init (State=Connecting)\n13:47:45.2971: Allowing 1 endpoint(s) 00:00:01 to respond...\n13:47:45.3004: Awaiting 1 available task completion(s) for 1000ms, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=8,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=45,Timers=11)\n13:47:45.3108: redisserver:6379/Interactive: Connected \n13:47:45.3183: redisserver:6379: Server handshake\n13:47:45.3536: redisserver:6379: Setting client name: scemodule-6c76dc7488-65ps7(SE.Redis-v2.7.17.27058)\n13:47:45.3724: redisserver:6379: Setting client lib/ver\n13:47:45.3757: redisserver:6379: Auto-configuring...\n13:47:45.3773: redisserver:6379: Requesting tie-break (Key=\"__Booksleeve_TieBreak\")...\n13:47:45.3785: redisserver:6379/Interactive: Writing: GET __Booksleeve_TieBreak\n13:47:45.3789: redisserver:6379: Sending critical tracer (handshake): ECHO\n13:47:45.3789: redisserver:6379/Interactive: Writing: ECHO\n13:47:45.3789: redisserver:6379: Flushing outbound buffer\n13:47:45.3789: redisserver:6379: OnEstablishingAsync complete\n13:47:45.3790: redisserver:6379: Starting read\n13:47:45.3960: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync completed (Disconnected)\n13:47:45.3976: All 1 available tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=7,Free=32760,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=8,QueuedItems=3,CompletedItems=59,Timers=10)\n13:47:45.3980: Endpoint summary:\n13:47:45.3987:   redisserver:6379: Endpoint is (Interactive: ConnectedEstablishing, Subscription: Connecting)\n13:47:45.3987: Task summary:\n13:47:45.3988:   **redisserver:6379: Returned, but incorrectly**\n13:47:45.4008: Election summary:\n13:47:45.4009:   Election: redisserver:6379 had no tiebreaker set\n13:47:45.4009:   Election: No primaries detected\n13:47:45.4014: Endpoint Summary:\n13:47:45.4022:   redisserver:6379: Standalone v3.0.0, primary; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: ConnectedEstablishing; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond\n13:47:45.4038:   redisserver:6379: int ops=24, qu=0, qs=12, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=12, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2\n13:47:45.4065: **Connection failed: redisserver:6379 (Subscription, SocketClosed): SocketClosed** (ReadEndOfStream, last-recv: 0) on redisserver:6379/Subscription, Flushed/MarkProcessed, last: SUBSCRIBE, origin: ReadFromPipe, outstanding: 5, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 9 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.7.17.27058\n13:47:45.4075: **Connection failed: redisserver:6379 (Interactive, SocketClosed): SocketClosed** (ReadEndOfStream, last-recv: 0) on redisserver:6379/Interactive, Flushed/MarkProcessed, last: CLIENT, origin: ReadFromPipe, outstanding: 11, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 9 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.7.17.27058\n13:47:45.4076: Connection failed: redisserver:6379 (Subscription, SocketClosed): SocketClosed (ReadEndOfStream, 0-sent, last-recv: 0) on redisserver:6379/Subscription, Flushed/MarkProcessed, last: SUBSCRIBE, origin: ReadFromPipe, outstanding: 5, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, unanswered-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: ConnectedEstablishing, mgr: 8 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.7.17.27058\n13:47:45.4161:   redisserver:6379: Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0+24=24 (2.40 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+12=12 (1.20 ops/s; spans 10s)\n13:47:45.4165: Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago\n13:47:45.4165: Resetting failing connections to retry...\n13:47:45.4172:   Retrying - attempts left: 2...\n13:47:45.4172: 1 unique nodes specified (with tiebreaker)\n13:47:45.4172: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync init (State=Connecting)\n13:47:45.4172: Allowing 1 endpoint(s) 00:00:01 to respond...\n13:47:45.4173: Awaiting 1 available task completion(s) for 1000ms, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=9,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=82,Timers=11)\n13:47:45.4185: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync completed (Disconnected)\n13:47:45.4186: All 1 available tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=6,Free=32761,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=9,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=91,Timers=9)\n13:47:45.4187: Endpoint summary:\n13:47:45.4187:   **redisserver:6379: Endpoint is (Interactive: Disconnected, Subscription: ConnectedEstablishing)\n13:47:45.4187: Task summary:\n13:47:45.4187:   redisserver:6379: Returned, but incorrectly**\n13:47:45.4187: Election summary:\n13:47:45.4187:   Election: redisserver:6379 had no tiebreaker set\n13:47:45.4187:   Election: No primaries detected\n13:47:45.4187: Endpoint Summary:\n13:47:45.4187:   redisserver:6379: Standalone v3.0.0, primary; keep-alive: 00:01:00; **int: Disconnected; sub: ConnectedEstablishing; not in use: DidNotRespond**\n13:47:45.4187:   redisserver:6379: int ops=36, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3; sub ops=13, qu=0, qs=2, qc=0, wr=0, socks=3\n13:47:45.4187:   redisserver:6379: Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0+36=36 (3.60 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+13=13 (1.30 ops/s; spans 10s)\n13:47:45.4188: Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago\n13:47:45.4188: Resetting failing connections to retry...\n13:47:45.4193:   Retrying - attempts left: 1...\n13:47:45.4193: 1 unique nodes specified (with tiebreaker)\n13:47:45.4193: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync init (State=Connecting)\n13:47:45.4193: Allowing 1 endpoint(s) 00:00:01 to respond...\n13:47:45.4193: Awaiting 1 available task completion(s) for 1000ms, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=9,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=97,Timers=11)\n13:47:45.4212: redisserver:6379: OnConnectedAsync completed (Disconnected)\n13:47:45.4212: All 1 available tasks completed cleanly, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=4,Free=32763,Min=8,Max=32767), POOL: (Threads=9,QueuedItems=1,CompletedItems=111,Timers=9)\n13:47:45.4213: Endpoint summary:\n13:47:45.4213:   **redisserver:6379: Endpoint is (Interactive: Disconnected, Subscription: Disconnected**)\n13:47:45.4213: Task summary:\n13:47:45.4213:   redisserver:6379: Returned, but incorrectly\n13:47:45.4213: Election summary:\n13:47:45.4213:   Election: redisserver:6379 had no tiebreaker set\n13:47:45.4213:   Election: No primaries detected\n13:47:45.4213: Endpoint Summary:\n13:47:45.4213:   redisserver:6379: Standalone v3.0.0, primary; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: **Disconnected**; sub: Disconnected; not in use: DidNotRespond\n13:47:45.4213:   redisserver:6379: int ops=48, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=4; sub ops=24, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=4\n13:47:45.4213:   redisserver:6379: Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0+48=48 (4.80 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+24=24 (2.40 ops/s; spans 10s)\n13:47:45.4213: Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago\n13:47:45.4215: Starting heartbeat...\n13:47:45.4226: Total connect time: 190 ms\